# C# Pass a generic delegate to constructor

Tags: c#, generics, constructor, delegates

I'm new to C# and I try to find a way to pass a generic delegate to a constructor.

When calling a show endpoint, if there is pagination, the endpoint should return a Page instance. When creating the Page instance, the delegate method should be passed as one of constructor parameters. ShowsEndpoints will host many endpoints and many of these endpoints use pagination. I want to use only one class to handle all endpoints.

```
public partial class ShowsEndpoints : Endpoint
{
    public Func<Task<IEnumerable<object>>> FetchPopularShowsAsyncDelegate;
    public Func<Task<IEnumerable<object>>> FetchTrendingShowsAsyncDelegate;
    public Func<Task<IEnumerable<object>>> FetchMostWatchedShowsAsyncDelegate;

    public async Task<IEnumerable<object>> FetchPopularShowsAsync(int page = 1, int limit = 20)
    {
        return await SendAsync(new PopularShowsRequest(page, limit));
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<object>> FetchTrendingShowsAsync(int page = 1, int limit = 20)
    {
        return await SendAsync(new TrendingShowsRequest(page, limit));
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<object>> FetchMostWatchedShowsAsync(int page = 1, int limit = 20)
    {
        return await SendAsync(new MostWatchedShowsRequest(page, limit));
    }
}
```

Page class which will call the delegate to fetch the next page if there is a next page.

```
public class Page<TItem, TDelegate>
{
    private TDelegate _delegateCommand;

    public int CurrentPage { get; }
    public int TotalPages { get; }
    public int PageItemsCount { get; }
    public int TotalItemsCount { get; }
    public IEnumerable<TItem> Items { get; }

    public Page(int page, int totalPages, int itemsCount, int totalItemsCount, IEnumerable<TItem> items, TDelegate delegateCommand)
    {
        CurrentPage = page;
        TotalPages = totalPages;
        PageItemsCount = itemsCount;
        TotalItemsCount = totalItemsCount;
        Items = items;
        _delegateCommand = delegateCommand;
    }

    public bool HasNext()
    {
        return CurrentPage <= TotalPages;
    }

    public bool HasPrevious()
    {
        return CurrentPage >= 1;
    }

    public Page<TItem, TDelegate> Next()
    {
        // call _delegateCommand to fetch the next page items
    }

    public Page<TItem, TDelegate> Previous()
    {
        // call _delegateCommand to fetch the previous page items
    }
}
```

Is it possible ?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

I have updated my classes code in order to understand better my question. I have 3 endpoints associated with their delegates and I want the `Page` class to use any of these 3 delegates with the same code to avoid duplication. So `_delegateCommand` can be `FetchPopularShowsAsyncDelegate`, `FetchTrendingShowsAsyncDelegate` or `FetchMostWatchedShowsAsyncDelegate`.

Comment: yes, but you should put a where clause in order to restrict/specify that this TDelegate should be Func so that you can use it properly inside your class... [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067(v=vs.100).aspx]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I've got the purpose of `_delegateCommand` right - I guess it should be the function returning `IEnumerable<TItem>`. If so, then you can declare it precisely like that, and then you won't have to introduce another generic parameter:

```
public class Page<TItem>
{
    private Func<IEnumerable<TItem>>_delegateCommand;

    public int CurrentPage { get; }
    public int TotalPages { get; }
    public int PageItemsCount { get; }
    public int TotalItemsCount { get; }
    public IEnumerable<TItem> Items { get; }

    public Page(int page, int totalPages, int itemsCount,
                int totalItemsCount, IEnumerable<TItem> items,
                Func<IEnumerable<TItem>> delegateCommand)
    {
        CurrentPage = page;
        TotalPages = totalPages;
        PageItemsCount = itemsCount;
        TotalItemsCount = totalItemsCount;
        Items = items;
        _delegateCommand = delegateCommand;
    }

    public bool HasNext()
    {
        return CurrentPage <= TotalPages;
    }

    public bool HasPrevious()
    {
        return CurrentPage >= 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I think it will not accomplish what I want to do. I have updated my classes code in order to better understand. I have 3 endpoints associated with their delegates and I want the Page class to use any of these 3 delegates with the same code to avoid duplication. So `_delegateCommand` can be `FetchPopularShowsAsyncDelegate`, `FetchTrendingShowsAsyncDelegate` or `FetchMostWatchedShowsAsyncDelegate`.